# Alien movie with long-legged dude

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I only saw part of this movie, probably from 1990-2000.

The villain is a guy wearing a fedora hat that is part-alien and can transform and doesn't have legs but has robot legs. He can breath fire from the top of his head and is really tall.

In the scene I recall, there’s a guy from Tokyo saying,

> "This is why I left Tokyo"

Answer (score 16):

This is [Inspector Gadget](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0141369/?ref_=tt_ch) (1999). The titular character is not an alien but rather a cyborg policeman.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also note that the titular guy is not meant to be the villain, but if you miss the beginning of the film and just go by the damage he causes, oh well, easy mistake to make.

Comment: @MrLister - I'd actually forgotten how bad this film was. I should probably post my usual disclaimer that instead of watching this tripe, OP would be better using their time to take a long bath, learn some conversational Japanese or practice [making the perfect omelette](https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/videos/techniques/how-make-perfect-omelette-video).

Comment: @Valorum I actually saw it in a theater as I was living in Pittsburgh at the time and it was partially filmed there.  Ahh memories!

Comment: @Valorum or just watch the [original cartoon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_xjBPdFILQk).